# Mock.mockImplementation is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, unit-testing, jestjs

I've tried to search every single similar issue here, unfortunately no solution worked for me.

I'm currently trying to mock named exports from a module, that looks like this:

**module.ts**

```js
export function someFunctionOne() {
    // implementation
}

export const someFunctionTwo = function (
) {
    // implementation
}

export const someFunctionThree = () => {
    // implementation
}

export const someFunctionFour = () => {
    // implementation
}
```

There are four exports here, and in my tests, I need to mock the whole module:

- Two exports shall be mocked initially to some value, then re-mocked by some tests (but not all)
- Two exports shall only be mocked initially and do not need to be re-mocked as I rely on the same mock for every tests

Tests look like this:

**module.test.ts**

```js
import React from 'react'
import { shallow } from 'enzyme'
import Component from './component' // component I am testing
import { someFunctionOne, someFunctionTwo  } from './module'

;(jest as any).mock('./module', () => ({
    someFunctionOne: jest.fn(),
    someFunctionTwo: jest.fn(),
    someFunctionThree: jest.fn(() => 10),
    someFunctionFour: jest.fn((s) => s),
}))
;(someFunctionOne as any).mockReturnValue('some String')
;(someFunctionTwo as any).mockReturnValue(false)


describe('Component', () => {
    beforeEach(() => {
        ;(someFunctionOne as any).mockReset()
        ;(someFunctionTwo as any).mockReset()
    })
    it('renders', () => {
        ;(someFunctionOne as any).mockImplementationOnce(jest.fn(() => 'some string'))
        ;(someFunctionTwo as any).mockImplementationOnce(jest.fn(() => false))
        const shallowRenderedModule = shallow(
            <Module>
                <div>Children textContent here</div>
            </Module>
        )
        expect(shallowRenderedModule).toMatchSnapshot()
    })
    // Then, many other tests...
})
```

I also have `jest` and `babel-jest` configured as so:

**jest.config.js**

```js
module.exports = {
    displayName: 'redacted-app',
    setupFilesAfterEnv: ['./jest/jest.setup'],
    preset: '../../jest.preset.js',
    transform: {
        '^.+\\.[tj]sx?$': [
            'babel-jest',
            { cwd: __dirname, configFile: './babel-jest.config.json' },
        ],
        '\\.(svg)$': './jest/svg.transform',
    },
    moduleFileExtensions: ['ts', 'tsx', 'js', 'jsx'],
}
```

**babel-jest.config.json**

```
{
    "presets": [
        [
            "@babel/preset-env",
            {
                "targets": {
                    "node": "current"
                }
            }
        ],
        "@babel/preset-typescript",
        "@babel/preset-react"
    ]
}
```

The problem is, no matter what method I use from `Mock` (`mockImplementation`, `mockReturnValue`, etc) I always end up with `_moduleName.someFunctionOne.mockReturnValue is not a function`:

```
    TypeError: _moduleName.someFunctionOne.mockReturnValue is not a function

      10 |      someFunctionFour: jest.fn((s) => s),
      11 | }))
    > 12 | ;(someFunctionOne as any).mockReturnValue('some String')
         |                     ^
      13 | ;(someFunctionTwo as any).mockReturnValue(false)
```

`console.log`ging it, it seems that indeed, the exports aren't actually mocked.

I'm at a loss here, what could it be?
I've tried:

- Using a dummy function inside the original `jest.fn()` e.g `jest.fn(() => {})`
- Not using a jest mock function at all in the original mock e.g `someFunctionOne: () => {}`
- Not using `mockReturnValue` in line 12 and mock it directly in `jest.fn()`
- Chaining `mockImplementationOnce` to the initial module mock

But none of these worked.

Comment: There should be `__esModule: true` in module mock. But that `someFunctionOne` is not `undefined` means that a mock simply wasn't applied. This can happen if jest.mock isn't hoisted, this is specific to your project and likely means that you misconfigured Jest and Babel.

Comment: @EstusFlask I forgot to mentioned that I've tried that as well. However I simply disregarded it as unrelated, as `_esModule` should simply bring support to mock default exports for ESM, which I don't use here as you've correctly noted. Is there anything specific you would look out for in jest and babel config?

Comment: `__esModule` affects how named exports are handled. Omitting it may result in a module with no named exports. See https://jestjs.io/docs/next/code-transformation#defaults . You need babel-jest to be in effect somehow.

Comment: I've tried using `_esModule` again and can confirm the named exports are the same as before. Also, I'm using `babel-jest`, so I've just posted the config for `jest` and `babel-jest`. I don't see anything that could cause it there.
One thing to note is I'm using `nx` to manage the monorepo this project is part of, I thought it could've potentially been the issue but explicitly running `jest --config=jest.config.js` produces the same error.

Comment: I don't see obvious problem there. Try to mock it a way it should definitely fail, `jest.mock('./module', () => null)`. If it doesn't try to avoid hoisting by changing `import` to `require` and putting it below jest.mock.

Answer (score 15):

I had similiar issues with mockimplementation is not a function and just realised I forgot the jest.setup.js file.

You probably already checked that, but have you looked in jest.setup.js instead of jest.config.js if you added the module there (`jest.mock('...')`);

That solved it for me as I wanted to mock a service. Was probably something I easily overlooked.

Comment: Sorry, what exactly do I need to add to jest.setup.js file? What is `jest.mock('...')`?